# RN None of these files exist: * aws-exports

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I initialized a new react native project with Amplify.

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
amplify configure
npm install -g expo-cli
```

```
expo init RNAmplify
cd RNAmplify
amplify init
```

```
npm install aws-amplify aws-amplify-react-native @react-native-community/netinfo @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify'
import config from './aws-exports'
Amplify.configure(config)
```

And I keep getting this response when I reload the app.
The aws-amplify, aws-amplify-react-native are present in the node_modules directory.

```
Unable to resolve module ./aws-exports from C:\Users\Masi\IdeaProjects\RNAmplify\App.js: 

None of these files exist:
  * aws-exports(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * aws-exports\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look in folder "src"

Comment: what do you mean look in folder "src"?

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was that I actually needed to run `amplify init` which creates an amplify folder for you after you answer a few questions.

Comment: what exactly the solution of the problem is? Can u explain your answer?

Comment: So you won't have an aws-config file unless you run amplify init. When you install amplify cli, after navigating to your source folder, either running amplify init or running amplify add auth, should give you a config file. The issue here is that the user likely does not have that file existing in their base folder.